# TCP write operation (in a non-blocking mode) sometimes blocks for more then a few msec

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, network-programming, nonblocking

I'm having a weird blocking issue when streaming data over TCP from client to server.
My client opens a TCP socket in a `non-blocking` mode.
Most of the time, everything is ok and the `write` calls return immediately (500-700 usec).
But sometimes, the `write` method is been blocked for a few consecutive `write` calls, and then back to normal (`write` calls return immediately (500-700 usec)).

In one of the times the issue happened, I've noticed that the data I need to write is in the size of `1324752 bytes`, while the pending data (I used `ioctl(c->fd, SIOCOUTQ, &pending)` for that) in the TCP socket queue was `331188 bytes`, and then the `write` call blocked for `0.9 msec`.
On the next write the data I need to write is in the size of `1249300 bytes`, while the pending data in the TCP socket queue was `330144 bytes`, and then the `write` call blocked for `22 msec`.
The following write operations also took a few msec (13 msec and 4 msec) and then things started to cool down and back to normal...
I'll try to summarize it in a table were:

- **seq number** 2269863 is the first write operation in this trace (2269864 is the second operation etc.)
- **data size** is the size of the data we need to send.
- **nwritten** is the actual data we had succeed to send.
- **pending data** is the amount of unsent data in the socket send queue.
- **write duration** is time that the write operation was blocking.

| seq number | data size [bytes] | nwritten [bytes] | pending data [bytes] | write duration [usec] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2269863 | 1324752 | 225992 | 331188 | 934 |
| 2269864 | 1249300 | 718431 | 330144 | **22227** |
| 2269865 | 651301 | 651301 | 0 | **13648** |
| 2269866 | 150540 | 150540 | 0 | 4262 |
| 2269867 | 30108 | 30108 | 0 | 755 |
| 2269868 | 30108 | 30108 | 0 | 754 |
| 2269869 | 30108 | 30108 | 0 | 613 |
| 2269870 | 30108 | 30108 | 0 | 857 |
| 2269871 | 30108 | 30108 | 0 | 555 |
| 2269872 | 30108 | 30108 | 0 | 569 |
| 2269873 | 30108 | 30108 | 0 | 636 |
| 2269874 | 30108 | 30108 | 0 | 814 |
| 2269875 | 30108 | 30108 | 0 | 812 |

**Some important notes:**

- I've verified that the NON_BLOCKING flag is set.
- I'm running 6 TCP clients, sending their data to the same TCP server - when the write method is been blocked, it happens on most the clients simultaneously (sometimes on all of them).
- The server runs on linux 4.15 and the clients run on linux 4.19.

**Question:**
Why does the write blocks for so long (were it's configured as a non-blocking operation) ?

Any tips or ideas are more then welcome,
Thanks !!

Comment: Sounds like CPU load -- if there's a context switch in the middle of `write`, you'll see time pass even though it did not block, and high CPU load often ramps up and back down, affecting a few consecutive scheduler quanta.

Comment: @BenVoigt, that was my first guess. But what are the chances that all clients suffer from a CPU load simultaneously ? (it happens once in a few minutes on all clients simultaneously)

Comment: Would the clients be processing the previous reply in parallel with sending the next one?  Or are the reaching the same stage of progress in doing some work?  There are a number of ways you could have correlation between clients.

Comment: At the very least I would be trying to compare elapsed wall-clock time and elapsed process CPU time to see if a context switch could be at fault (but this won't help you for cycles stolen by other threads in the same process)

Comment: Check the results of `getrusage()` in particular you want to calculate the deltas across the "blocking" `write()` calls.

Comment: @BenVoigt, thanks for the trick with the wall-clock and process CPU time - however the issue it not there... I will try to investigate in the server side (perhaps we have a CPU load issue in the server side)

Comment: Did you ever figure out what the issue is? I have a similar issue but with much less data (on windows though).

Comment: @Bas It's been a while, but if I'm not mistaken I think it was a memory swap issue. After I disabled the swappiness mechanism, the problem was solved. It's a very spesific and private solution. I doubt if that's the same issue you are suffering from ... But wish you luck :)